# How to dynamically configure security for Artemis MQ addresses

Tags: activemq-artemis

Trying to dynamically create and provide security metadata for artemis mq topics (as opposed to defining them statically in broker.xml).
For that purpose I've implemented (as described [here](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.2.0/security.html)) the `SecuritySettingPlugin` interface.
Now, the issue is the `getSecurityRoles/populateSecurityRoles` of the implementation are called only at server startup.
So, at some point in time after the mq server has been started, a topic will be created :

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.management.JMSServerControl.createTopic("newTopic")
```

Now I would like artemis to call again my `SecuritySettingPlugin` implementation to get the updated security roles (which will include configuration for the newly created `newTopic`).
Is that possible ?

P.S. `security-invalidation-interval` does not invalidate roles configuration cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a way to customize an address security by API :
[ActiveMQServerControl](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-1.2.0/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html).[addSecuritySettings](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-1.2.0/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#addSecuritySettings-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)()